# Where to look up names of .NET assemblies that contain a class or namespace?

Tags: .net, ironpython

In .NET scripting languages such as PowerShell and IronPython, when you want to use a .NET class you typically need to import the assembly name.  Is there a quick way to find this information?

E.g. if I want to use System.Net.Mail, how do I quickly find out which assembly its in?  I'm not necessarily looking for a programmatic way, even an online reference will do.  The MSDN .NET class reference doesn't seem to tell you this (e.g. [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx))

I only care about standard .NET classes, obviously there is no standard namespace/class to assembly mapping for custom and 3rd party classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN does contain this information. If you check the documentation page for a class (such as [`System.Net.Mail.Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx)) it lists the namespace and assembly name at the top of the page, right under the class name headline.

Comment: I'm ashamed.  Thank you for humoring me.

Answer (score 5):

Red Gate's .NET Reflector is also a quick way to check.